# reactJS form input element validates but does not update

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms

I have a form in a reactJS application.  Here is the code so far (sorry if its a lot)

```
import React from 'react';
import '../styles/app.css';

function validateDollar(value) {
var regex = /^[1-9]\d*(((,\d{3}){1})?(\.\d{0,2})?)$/;
if (regex.test(value))
{
    //Input is valid, check the number of decimal places
    var twoDecimalPlaces = /\.\d{2}$/g;
    var oneDecimalPlace = /\.\d{1}$/g;
    var noDecimalPlacesWithDecimal = /\.\d{0}$/g;

    if(value.match(twoDecimalPlaces))
    {
        //all good, return as is
        return value;
    } 
    else 
    {
      if(value.match(noDecimalPlacesWithDecimal))
      {
          //add two decimal places
          return value + "00";
      }
      else
      {
        if(value.match(oneDecimalPlace ))
        {
            //ad one decimal place
            return value + "0";
        }
        else
        {
        //else there is no decimal places and no decimal
        return value + ".00";               
        }           
      }
    }
}
else
{
  return -1;
}
}

class Enterproperty extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = { 
    numberUnits: 0,
    name: {
      valid: true,
      value: '',
      label: 'Property Nickname',
      length: 0,
      css: 'input-group-text text-black input-size-200'
    },
    address: {
      valid: true,
      value: '',
      label: 'Property Address',
      length: 0,
      css: 'input-group-text text-black input-size-200'
    },
    city: {
      valid: true,
      value: '',
      label: 'Property City',
      length: 0,
      css: 'input-group-text text-black input-size-200'
    },
    price: {
      valid: true,
      value: '',
      label: 'Asking price',
      length: 0,
      css: 'input-group-text text-black input-size-200'
    },
    taxes: {
      valid: true,
      value: '',
      label: 'Taxes per year',
      length: 0,
      css: 'input-group-text text-black input-size-200'
    },
    expenses: {
      valid: true,
      value: '',
      label: 'Net Operating Expenses',
      length: 0,
      css: 'input-group-text text-black input-size-200'
    },
    caprate: {
      valid: true,
      value: '',
      label: 'Cap Rate',
      length: 0,
      css: 'input-group-text text-black input-size-200'
    },
    yearbuilt: {
      valid: true,
      value: '',
      label: 'Building built in:',
      length: 0,
      css: 'input-group-text text-black input-size-200'
    },
    numberofunits: {
      valid: true,
      value: '',
      label: 'Nuber of units:',
      length: 0,
      css: 'input-group-text text-black input-size-200'
    }
  }

  this.saveData = this.saveData.bind(this);
  this.yearBuilt = this.yearBuilt.bind(this);
  this.setUnitNumber = this.setUnitNumber.bind(this);

} 


setUnitNumber() {

  let currentComponent = this;

  var localUnitCount = document.getElementById("inputNumberOfUnits").value;
  currentComponent.setState({ numberUnits:localUnitCount });

}

saveData() {
let currentComponent = this;

var validData = true;
var localName = {
  valid: true,
  value: '',
  label: 'Property Nickname',
  length: 0,
  css: 'input-group-text text-black input-size-200'
}
var localAddress = {
  valid: true,
  value: '',
  label: 'Property Address',
  length: 0,
  css: 'input-group-text text-black input-size-200'
}
var localCity = {
  valid: true,
  value: '',
  label: 'Property City',
  length: 0,
  css: 'input-group-text text-black input-size-200'
}
var localPrice = {
  valid: true,
  value: '',
  label: 'Asking price',
  length: 0,
  css: 'input-group-text text-black input-size-200'
}
var localExpenses = {
  valid: true,
  value: '',
  label: 'Net Operating Expenses',
  length: 0,
  css: 'input-group-text text-black input-size-200'
}
var localCapRate = {
  valid: true,
  value: '',
  label: 'Cap Rate',
  length: 0,
  css: 'input-group-text text-black input-size-200'
}
var localTaxes = {
  valid: true,
  value: '',
  label: 'Taxes per year',
  length: 0,
  css: 'input-group-text text-black input-size-200'
}

// validate the property nickname
localName.value = document.getElementById("lblName").value;
localName.length = localName.value.length;

if (localName.length < 5) {
  validData = false;
  localName.valid = false;
  //localName.label = "You did not enter a property nickname (minimum of 5 charaters)";
  localName.css = "input-group-text text-danger input-size-200";
}

// validate the property address
localAddress.value = document.getElementById("lblAddress").value;
localAddress.length = localAddress.value.length;

if (localAddress.length < 3) {
  validData = false;
  localAddress.valid = false;
  //localAddress.label = "You did not enter a property Address (minimum of 5 characters)";
  localAddress.css = "input-group-text text-danger input-size-200";
}

// validate the property city
localCity.value = document.getElementById("lblCity").value;
localCity.length = localCity.value.length;

if (localCity.length < 3) {
  validData = false;
  localCity.valid = false;
  //localCity.label = "You did not enter a property city (minimum of 3 characters)";
  localCity.css = "input-group-text text-danger input-size-200";
}

// validate the property price
localPrice.value = validateDollar(document.getElementById("lblPrice").value);

if (localPrice.value < 0){
  localPrice.value = "";
  validData = false;
  localPrice.valid = false;
  //localPrice.label = "You entered an invalid dollar amount for the cost of the building";
  localPrice.css = "input-group-text text-danger input-size-200";
}

// validate the property taxes
localTaxes.value = validateDollar(document.getElementById("lblTaxes").value);

if (localTaxes.value < 0){
  localTaxes.value = "";
  validData = false;
  localTaxes.valid = false;
  //localTaxes.label = "You entered an invalid dollar amount for the taxes on the building";
  localTaxes.css = "input-group-text text-danger input-size-200";
}

// validate the Cap Rate
localCapRate.value = validateDollar(document.getElementById("lblCapRate").value);

if (localCapRate.value < 0){
    localCapRate.value = "";
  validData = false;
  localCapRate.valid = false;
  //localTaxes.label = "You entered an invalid dollar amount for the taxes on the building";
  localCapRate.css = "input-group-text text-danger input-size-200";
}

// validate the net operating expenses
localExpenses.value = validateDollar(document.getElementById("lblExpenses").value);

if (localExpenses.value < 0){
    localExpenses.value = "";
  validData = false;
  localExpenses.valid = false;
  //localExpenses.label = "You entered an invalid dollar amount for the taxes on the building";
  localExpenses.css = "input-group-text text-danger input-size-200";
}

currentComponent.setState({ name:localName, address:localAddress, city:localCity, price:localPrice, taxes:localTaxes, expenses:localExpenses, caprate:localCapRate });

}

yearBuilt() {

  var date = new Date();
  var startYear = date.getFullYear();
  var endYear = startYear - 120;

  let items = [];         
  for (let i = startYear;i>endYear;i--) {             
      items.push(<option key={i} value={i}>{i}</option>);   
      //here I will be creating my options dynamically based on
      //what props are currently passed to the parent component
  }
  return items;

}


 renderData = () => {       

    var localUnitCount = this.state.numberUnits;
    var idArray = [];

    for (var counter=0;counter<localUnitCount;counter++) {
      var id = '';
      var idObject = {
        counter: 0,
        idNameBedroom: '',
        idNameBathroom: '',
        idRent: '',
        idMarket: '',
        idRentedStatus: ''
      }

      //build the id for the bedroom item
      if (counter<10) {id="Bedroom0"} else {id="Bedroom"};
      id=id+counter;
      idObject.idNameBedroom  = id+(counter+1);

      //build the id for the bathroom item
      if (counter<10) {id="Bathroom0"} else {id="Bathroom"};
      id=id+counter;
      idObject.idNameBathroom  = id+(counter+1);

      //build the id for the rent item
      if (counter<10) {id="Rent0"} else {id="Rent"};
      id=id+counter;
      idObject.idRent  = id;

      //build the id for the mareket item
      if (counter<10) {id="Market0"} else {id="Market"};
      id=id+counter;
      idObject.idMarket  = id;

      //build the id for the rented status item
      if (counter<10) {id="RentedStatus0"} else {id="RentedStatus"};
      id=id+counter;
      idObject.idRentedStatus  = id;

      idObject.counter = counter+1;
      idArray[counter] = idObject;

    }

    return idArray.map( item => (

        <div>
            <hr />
            <div className="text-black text-bold">
                <label> Unit {item.counter} </label>
            </div>    
            <div className="input-group mb-3">
                <div className="input-group-prepend">
                    <span className="input-group-text text-black input-size-200">Rent for Unit {item.counter}</span>
                </div>
                <input id={item.idRent} type="text" className="form-control" />
            </div> 
            <div className="input-group mb-3">
                <div className="input-group-prepend">
                    <span className="input-group-text text-black input-size-200">Rented status of Unit {item.counter}</span>
                </div>                                        
                <select className="custom-select text-black" id={item.idRentedStatus}>
                    <option value="rented" selected>Rented</option>
                    <option value="vacant">Vacant</option>
                </select>
            </div> 
            <div className="input-group mb-3">
                <div className="input-group-prepend">
                    <span className="input-group-text text-black input-size-200">Bedrooms in Unit {item.counter}</span>
                </div>                                        
                <select className="custom-select text-black" id={item.idNameBedroom}>
                    <option value="1" selected>1 bedroom</option>
                    <option value="2">2 bedrooms</option>
                    <option value="3">3 bedrooms</option>
                    <option value="4">4 bedrooms</option>
                    <option value="5">5 bedrooms</option>
                </select>
            </div> 
            <div className="input-group mb-3">
                <div className="input-group-prepend">
                    <span className="input-group-text text-black input-size-200">Bathrooms in Unit {item.counter}</span>
                </div>                                        
                <select className="custom-select text-black" id={item.idNameBathroom}>
                    <option value="1" selected>1 bathroom</option>
                    <option value="2">2 bathrooms</option>
                    <option value="3">3 bathrooms</option>
                    <option value="4">4 bathrooms</option>
                    <option value="5">5 bathrooms</option>
                </select>
            </div> 
            <div className="input-group mb-3">
                <div className="input-group-prepend">
                    <span className="input-group-text text-black input-size-200">Rent category for Unit {item.counter}</span>
                </div>                                        
                <select className="custom-select text-black" id={item.idMarket}>
                    <option value="market" selected>Market value</option>
                    <option value="stabalized">Rent stabalized</option>
                    <option value="controlled">Rent controlled</option>
                </select>
            </div> 
        </div>
      ) )
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.state.caprate.value);
    return (
        <div className="App">      
            <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
                <a className="navbar-brand" href="#">Property Management</a>
                <button className="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span className="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>

                <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                    <ul className="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                    <li className="nav-item">
                        <a className="nav-link" href="/loadProperty">View Saved Properties</a>
                    </li>
                    <li className="nav-item">
                        <a className="nav-link" href="/Enterproperty">Enter New Property</a>
                    </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>

            <div className="d-flex flex-wrap justify-content-center position-absolute w-100 align-items-center align-content-center">
                <div className="container">
                    <div className="row">
                        <div md="6">
                            <form>
                                <p className="h4 text-center py-4">Enter the property information</p>
                                <div className="input-group mb-3">
                                    <div className="input-group-prepend">
                                        <span className={this.state.name.css}>{this.state.name.label}</span>
                                    </div>
                                    <input id="lblName" type="text" className="form-control" />
                                </div> 
                                <div className="input-group mb-3">
                                    <div className="input-group-prepend">
                                        <span className={this.state.address.css}>{this.state.address.label}</span>
                                    </div>
                                    <input id="lblAddress" type="text" className="form-control" />
                                </div> 
                                <div className="input-group mb-3">
                                    <div className="input-group-prepend">
                                        <span className={this.state.city.css}>{this.state.city.label}</span>
                                    </div>
                                    <input id="lblCity" type="text" className="form-control" />
                                </div> 
                                <div className="input-group mb-3">
                                    <div className="input-group-prepend">
                                        <span className={this.state.price.css}>{this.state.price.label}</span>
                                    </div>
                                    <input id="lblPrice" type="text" className="form-control" />
                                </div> 
                                <div className="input-group mb-3">
                                    <div className="input-group-prepend">
                                        <span className={this.state.taxes.css}>{this.state.taxes.label}</span>
                                    </div>
                                    <input id="lblTaxes" type="text" className="form-control" />
                                </div> 
                                <div className="input-group mb-3">
                                    <div className="input-group-prepend">
                                        <span className={this.state.expenses.css}>{this.state.expenses.label}</span>
                                    </div>
                                    <input id="lblExpenses" type="text" className="form-control" />
                                </div> 
                                <div className="input-group mb-3">
                                    <div className="input-group-prepend">
                                        <span className={this.state.caprate.css}>{this.state.caprate.label}</span>
                                    </div>
                                    <input id="lblCapRate" type="text" className="form-control" value={this.state.caprate.value}/>
                                </div> 
                                <div className="input-group mb-3">
                                    <div className="input-group-prepend">
                                        <span className={this.state.yearbuilt.css}>Tax abatements?</span>
                                    </div>                                        
                                    <select className="custom-select text-black" id="inputTaxAbatement">
                                        <option value="yes" selected>Yes</option>
                                        <option value="no">No</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div> 
                                <div className="input-group mb-3">
                                    <div className="input-group-prepend">
                                        <span className={this.state.yearbuilt.css}>Fuel Type</span>
                                    </div>                                        
                                    <select className="custom-select text-black" id="inputFuelType">
                                        <option value="gas" selected>Gas</option>
                                        <option value="oil">Oil</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div> 
                                <div className="input-group mb-3">
                                    <div className="input-group-prepend">
                                        <span className={this.state.yearbuilt.css}>Tennants pay utilities</span>
                                    </div>                                        
                                    <select className="custom-select text-black" id="inputTennantsPayUtilities">
                                        <option value="yes" selected>Yes</option>
                                        <option value="no">No</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                                <div className="input-group mb-3">
                                    <div className="input-group-prepend">
                                        <span className={this.state.yearbuilt.css}>{this.state.yearbuilt.label}</span>
                                    </div>                                        
                                    <select className="custom-select text-black" id="inputYearBuilt">
                                        {this.yearBuilt()}
                                    </select>
                                </div> 
                                <div className="input-group mb-3">
                                    <div className="input-group-prepend">
                                        <span className={this.state.numberofunits.css}>{this.state.numberofunits.label}</span>
                                    </div>                                        
                                    <select className="custom-select text-black" id="inputNumberOfUnits" onChange={() => { 
                                    this.setUnitNumber();
                                    }}>
                                        <option value="0" selected>Select</option>
                                        <option value="1">One</option>
                                        <option value="2">Two</option>
                                        <option value="3">Three</option>
                                        <option value="4">Four</option>
                                        <option value="5">Five</option>
                                        <option value="6">Six</option>
                                        <option value="7">Seven</option>
                                        <option value="8">Eight</option>
                                        <option value="9">Nine</option>
                                        <option value="10">Ten</option>
                                        <option value="11">Eleven</option>
                                        <option value="12">Twelve</option>
                                        <option value="13">Thirteen</option>
                                        <option value="14">Fourteen</option>
                                        <option value="15">Fifteen</option>
                                        <option value="16">Sixteen</option>
                                        <option value="17">Seventeen</option>
                                        <option value="18">Eighteen</option>
                                        <option value="19">Nineteen</option>
                                        <option value="20">Twenty</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div> 
                                <div>
                                    {this.renderData()}
                                </div> 
                                <div className="text-center py-4 mt-3">
                                    <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary" onClick={() => { 
                                    this.saveData();
                                    }}>Save</button>
                                </div> 
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
}

export default Enterproperty;
```

The code in the saveData() validates the values of the input fields.

I am specifically looking at the numeric fields where I need to make sure they are entered as dollar amount.

After validating the fields, I execute a setState to update the state with the new values. Once the state is updated, react will re-render and the form is displayed.

My issue is, if I enter 12345 into the form field for cap rate and click the button, my console.log() shows that I validate the value 12345 to "12345.00".  I have a console.log() in the render right before the return() and the value of this.state.caprate.value is 12345.00 but when the render happens, the form still shows the old value.

What is the proper way to validate the field and have the field editable after the validation is finished?

Comment: But you need to use `parseInt` to convert the number string to number... `parseInt(document.getElementById("lblCapRate").value)`. Everything comes from browsers are string..

Comment: @ArupRakshit I dont use parseInt.  I call a function that contains a regular expression to validate the input.  the code that I execute to validate the field is this: localCapRate.value = validateDollar(document.getElementById("lblCapRate").value);  This will return 12345.00 if I send it 12345.  And then I update the state with a setState command.  The state gets updated according to the console.log that I have after my render() statement but it does not show in the text box.

Comment: How are you converting the "12345.00" to 12345.00?.. then I guess `validateDollar()` function is doing it for you..

Comment: @ArupRakshit I have modified my post to show my entire application.  This may help to better demonstrate what I am trying to do.